# In a premake script, how do you get the "kind" of a project?

Tags: lua, post-build-event, premake

I am trying to add a post-build step which runs an executable on the project after it compiles. To do this, the compiler needs to know if it an .exe or a .dll before hand. How can I find the extension of a project (or premake 'kind') during the premake step? I am using premake 4.3 and visual studio 2010. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Premake4 there is no great way to do that. Your best bet will probably be duplicating the commands with configuration filters.

```
configuration { "ConsoleApp or WindowedApp" }
   postbuildcommands { "thecmd --kind=exe" }
configuration { "StaticLib or SharedLib" }
   postbuildcommands { "thecmd --kind=lib" }
```

In Premake5 you could use tokens.

```
postbuildcommands { 
   "thecmd --kind=%{iif(cfg.kind:endswith("App"), "exe", "lib")}" 
}
```